# Error message "Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10515fd44)" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, breakpoints

I have been getting these error messages in debug window in Xcode:

```
2023-06-06 07:46:15.412684-0500 Courier[8456:442818] [LayoutConstraints] Unsupported layout off the main thread for _UIModernBarButton with nearest ancestor view controller, UINavigationController
2023-06-06 07:46:15.413268-0500 Courier[8456:442818] [Assert] -[UIImageView _invalidateImageLayouts] must be called on the main queue
2023-06-06 07:46:15.413730-0500 Courier[8456:442818] [Assert] -[UIImageView _layoutForImage:inSize:cachePerSize:forBaselineOffset:] must be called on the main queue
(lldb)
```

The messages come when my code crashes and gives this error message in a red ribbon in the editor window:

```
Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10515fd44)
```

In the Debug navigator on the left pane of Xcode, it shows the code stopped at:

```
#0  0x000000010515fd44 in _dispatch_assert_queue_fail ()
```

This is what shows at the end in the editor window. At the very end is where the error message in the red ribbon shows:

```
    0x10515fd10 <+68>:  add    x9, x9, #0xf2f            ; "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Assertion failed: "
    0x10515fd14 <+72>:  stp    x9, x8, [sp]
    0x10515fd18 <+76>:  adrp   x1, 65
    0x10515fd1c <+80>:  add    x1, x1, #0xefa            ; "%sBlock was %sexpected to execute on queue [%s (%p)]"
    0x10515fd20 <+84>:  sub    x0, x29, #0x18
    0x10515fd24 <+88>:  bl     0x10519cfc8               ; symbol stub for: asprintf
    0x10515fd28 <+92>:  ldur   x19, [x29, #-0x18]
    0x10515fd2c <+96>:  str    x19, [sp]
    0x10515fd30 <+100>: adrp   x0, 65
    0x10515fd34 <+104>: add    x0, x0, #0xf65            ; "%s"
    0x10515fd38 <+108>: bl     0x1051986b0               ; _dispatch_log
    0x10515fd3c <+112>: adrp   x8, 98
    0x10515fd40 <+116>: str    x19, [x8, #0x268]
->  0x10515fd44 <+120>: brk    #0x1
```

I have no idea which code is causing the error, so I don't even know what code to put in my question.

I created a symbolic breakpoint with 'LayoutConstraints' in the Symbol field. It is never tripped.

I get no purple warnings that says a line of code should not be in the main thread.

I have no idea where to go from here. I don't ind anything when I do a search in the internet that is narrowed down to address my error.

I am running the code on an iPhone 13 Pro Max device with iOS 16.5.

I am using Xcode 14.3 on a Mac Pro running Ventura 13.4

Comment: Are you setting an image for a navigation bar button?

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem at present, but I have tried to cancel the Debug executable and the app can run normally.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34859877)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The messages are telling you that there is something causing views in your app to be modified from a background thread.

Do you have any code in your app that could be calling things off of the main queue (i.e. do you use a global DispatchQueue anywhere? Do you use NSThread anywhere? Do you use a networking library that might be calling back to you on a background thread? etc.).